# Why does my Tor talk to activate.adobe.com?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

[image: Capture]
As shown in the attached picture, can anyone give me a hint why my Tor.exe talk to the host of Adobe? while I am not using Tor to access or use any Adobe services. does my PC get hacked or injected by virus?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not relevant for others. You used some cracked software which seems to phone home. See also http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/q/248

Comment: Sure! please close it. I am so sorry for any inconvenience caused to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you should provide the IP address, not a hostname (the thing in the "address" field is a hostname) from your connection tracking tool. Resolving the hostname leaks where you're connecting and makes debugging pretty hard, because we don't know if there is an issue with your DNS being broken or something else. As to your question, activate.adobe.com seems to be offline currently and not running a Tor relay, so there's no reason for it to connect there. I think it's unlikely you have a virus that would be causing this issue.

... and as discovered in the comments, Tor never connected to activate.adobe.com.

Comment: the picture I took is from the Task Manager of Windows OS, it does not provide me IP address. I just tried to use Tor to access Youtube only, but the activate.adobe.com is still showing up in the Task Manager.

Comment: try the resource monitor to list tcp connections and see if that gives you an ip address?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Since I am running TBB behind a proxy to connect to the Internet, so I think Wireshark will not help cos destination IP will always be my proxy's IP.

Comment: So sorry, for my privacy, I cannot reveal my Proxy here cos it's an institute's private proxy. All connection to outside Internet have to go through the proxy server. I will try to figure out, and upload more hints if I get any.

Comment: ok, that's fair. My point is that it looks like the reverse dns for your proxy might be resolving to activate.adobe.com, for whatever reason. Please try to learn if that is true?

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm just afraid that my PC got spied or virus injected in it.

Comment: as I said, I think that's unlikely. Let's not spam the comments more, please remember to update your question if you learn more details and accept an answer once you are satisfied.

Comment: Dear Sebastian, I think I already figured it. I tried to reset DNS setting in my network connection interface, and it reveals that activate.adobe.com pointing to IP:127.0.0.1. I think it is because I am using a cracked version of Acrobat, and the way Acrobat got cracked is point the activate.adobe.com to 127.0.0.1 so that the auto-update and auto-activate functions of Acrobat will not talk to real activate.adobe.com, thus black-list my Acrobat. Is that right?